# How can I send a contact from one Android to another?

Tags: contacts, share-menu

While I can chose `Share` by a contact on my Droid's contact list, the Droid on the other end seems unable to open, or really do anything with, the resulting attachment if I receive it via Gmail or the normal mail client. Am I missing something? How do I import what I've shared?

Answer (score 5):

There is an app called [Hoccer](http://www.hoccer.com/) which allows transfer of arbitrary data (contacts, pictures, links, ...) by making gestures with your phone. It also works with the iPhone but of course requires both devices to have the app installed.

Answer (score 5):

It's a known issue that Android (at least pre-2.2) does not support import of .vcf files via email or sms, see http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3537

However, it does appear to work in Froyo on my Nexus One, when importing from email. As far as I'm aware it's still not catered for over SMS, and the thread above suggests it doesn't work for downloads in the browser either.

Comment: Amazingly, still true, I think, for Android 6.0.  Issue 3537 was marked as a duplicate of 2412, which is "Obsolete" with no fix that I noticed in a quick perusal.   What's up?   https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2412

Answer (score 5):

If both droids are in the same room the following will apply - You can both install Barcode Scanner and then on your device, open the contact, tap share, then tap Barcode Scanner. This will generate a QR Code. On the other phone, open the barcode scanner app and scan the QR Code. The second device will be able to add the contact via the scanned QR Code via the Add as Contact button after the scan successfully completes.

Answer (score 1):

There's also [Bump](http://www.appbrain.com/app/bump/com.bumptech.bumpga).

> Bump™ makes sharing photos, contacts,
>   and apps with people as simple as
>   bumping your phones together.
>
> HOW TO USE BUMP™:  1) Open Bump™ on
>   both phones 2) While holding the
>   phones, gently bump your hands
>   together  3) Confirm the exchange
>
> Compatible with iPhone too!

Answer (score 0):

I've got an Sony Ericsson Xperia X10 and while viewing a contact, I just press the menu button, Send Business Card and choose between Bluetooth, Gmail, SMS or Moxier Mail (Exchange Client I think).

I've send contacts back and forth between my Android phone and my Palm phone. I don't have two Android phones, but I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Previously I was using 1.6 which was fully compatible with all my contacts on my old Palm phone, but since upgrading to 2.1 this does not work as well as I had hoped.

So, no software to install, works right out of the box for me.